# How do I build a dockerfile if the name of the dockerfile isn't Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I am able a build a Dockerfile like

`docker build -t deepak/ruby .`

But for a Dockerfile which is not named `Dockerfile`

```
# DOCKER-VERSION 0.4.8

FROM deepak/ruby

MAINTAINER Deepak Kannan "deepak@example.com"

RUN ./bin/rails s
```

let us say it is called `Dockerfile.app`
which we build with

`docker build -t deepak/app Dockerfile.app`

then i get the error

```
Uploading context 0 bytes
Error build: EOF
EOF
```

Comment: So your question is, how do I build a dockerfile if the name of the dockerfile isn't Dockerfile?

Comment: @KenCochrane yes. that is the question

Comment: If you run ```docker build --help``` there is a line where you can find what you are looking for:   -f, --file string                Name of the Dockerfile (Default is 'PATH/Dockerfile')

Comment: for me specifying the whole path in the `-f` option worked e.g. `docker build -f ~/iit-term-synthesis/Dockerfile_arm -t brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test_arm ~/iit-term-synthesis/`

Answer (score 570):

Notice there is a dot `.` at the end of both commands.

```
docker build -f MyDockerfile .
```

Or with a tag:

```
docker build -t mysuperimage -f MyDockerfile .
```

Comment: `docker build -f Dockerfile.consumer` gives me an error
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Comment: @kamal did you notice a dot ( `.`) at the end of above command?

Comment: The `.` is not a required thing. The build command takes two args viz. path to `Dockerfile` & path to `context` directory. So, we can do `docker build -t mysupertag -f ./foo/Dockerfile ./foo`

Comment: @Mohnish I don't get it, what does the last `./foo` do in the command? I understand the first is the path to the dockerfile with the name of the docker file.

Comment: for me specifying the whole path in the `-f` option worked e.g. `docker build -f ~/iit-term-synthesis/Dockerfile_arm -t brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test_arm ~/iit-term-synthesis/`

Comment: @CharlieParker The second arg `./foo` refers to the context directory to be used for the build - aka the directory whose contents are going to be copied into the build & that's supposed to contain the Dockerfile.

Comment: Why is there a dot at the end if we are specifying a file with `-f`?

Comment: Because the context directory doesn't have to be the same as the Dockerfile directory.

Answer (score 104):

This Works

```
docker build -t doronaviguy/helloworld -f SomeDockerFile .
```

[Docker build Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/build/)

Comment: Mine required -t to add the tag.

Comment: what does the last `.` do?

Comment: @CharlieParker Seeing your questions, maybe you're missing this - in CLI, `.` means '_the current directory_'.

Answer (score 26):

The last parameter to docker build is the build path, when you put `.` it means this is the path where you will find the `Dockerfile`. When you change it to `Dockerfile.app` it will then try and look for `Dockerfile.app/Dockerfile`, which isn't correct.

I'm not sure if it will still work, but you used to be able to do this.

```
$ docker build -t deepak/app - < Dockerfile.app
```

Try that and see if it helps, if not, maybe open a docker issue to add this feature back in, or update the documentation on how to use a Dockerfile with a different name.

More info here: http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/commandline/command/build/

Comment: i have tried a url and it works. Path also should work according to docs. will file a bug.

Comment: according to the docs you shared (thanks). `docker build - < Dockerfile` will not allow me to ADD a local file. But have tried it out and it works

Comment: but i want to give a different Dockerfile and still have a context ie. ADD files. so i will file a bug

Comment: This will just create a context with a single Dockerfile in it. All supporting files will not make it into the context.

Comment: `docker build -f Dockerfile.app -t deepak/app .` works when requires `COPY` local files

Answer (score 22):

Try [dockerfeed](https://github.com/itsafire/dockerfeed). It uses the docker feature to build a context via stdin. I wrote the script to address exactly your problem I was facing myself.

To replace a Dockerfile with a different one you do it like this:

```
dockerfeed -d Dockerfile.app . | docker build -t deepak/ruby -
```

And voilà. Dockerfeed is doing the same as `docker build`. It packs the source with its Dockerfile but lets you swap out the old Dockerfile with the desired one. No files are created in the process, no source is changed. The generated tar archive is piped into docker, which in turn sends it down to the docker daemon.

**Update:** 
This was a valid answer in the old days when there was no `-f` switch available. With docker version 1.5 this option was introduced. Now you can build provide a different Dockerfile like this:

```
docker build -f other-Dockerfile .
```

Comment: what does the last `.` do?

Comment: `docker build` required one argument. The context. Generally it is the current directory where you execute `docker build`. The directory containing the Dockerfile and probably some support files, the Dockerfile will copy into the image. The last dot is the path to the current directory. Alternatively you could write out the absolute path to the image definition: `docker build /home/peter/my-image`

Answer (score 20):

This should work,

`docker build -t <tag-name> -f <file-name> .`

Comment: what does the last `.` do?

Comment: @CharlieParker It gives the folder context that Docker will look for files in. When you use the COPY command in the Dockerfile it can only copy files from the context it was provided in the build command. In this case "." is the current working directory

Answer (score 9):

You can acheive this also using docker-compose.

In your docker-compose.yml under the build section, you can specify the directory in which you store your dockerfile and its alternate-name as follow :

```
build:
  context: "/path/to/docker/directory"
  dockerfile: "dockerfile-alternate-name"
```

[docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

Answer (score 4):

Windows User should try below command:

> docker build -f absolute_docker_file_path dot

for example :

> docker build -f D:\Code\core-api\API_TEST.Dockerfile .

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple `Dockerfile`'s, as could be the case in large projects, you could specify the respective fully-qualified `Dockerfile` to use.

```
docker build -t swagger_local -f /Users/123456/myrepos/storage/services/gateway/swagger/Dockerfile .
```

The command when run from `/Users/123456/myrepos/storage` creates a `swagger_local` image using the `Dockerfile` in a child project (`services/gateway` in my case )

Comment: This was my problem, that I was using a relative path wrt the build context path instead of the fully-qualified path

Answer (score 1):

My case is in the `/tmp` directory and there are a lot of files and docker try with others files althought I pass the `-f <Dockerfile.foo>`

The most clean and easy (for me) solution is (intead the `dockerfeed` from above answers):

```
cat DockerFile.debian.foo | docker build -t debian.foo -
```

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that you have successfully install docker toolbox including **docker-compose** and **docker-machine**. This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services: 
  web: ./www/python
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
```

And this is under Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.4-alpine
ADD ./www/python /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Make sure those files located precisely under root folder. When you run docker-compose up then you are going to build image for web.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked once I put the entire path in the file option:

```
(meta_learning) brandomiranda~ ❯ docker build -f ~/iit-term-synthesis/Dockerfile_arm -t brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test_arm ~/iit-term-synthesis/

[+] Building 43.8s (9/28)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile_arm                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.59kB                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/continuumio/miniconda3:latest                                                                           0.0s
 => [ 1/24] FROM docker.io/continuumio/miniconda3                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED https://api.github.com/repos/IBM/pycoq/git/refs/heads/main                                                                              0.0s
 => [ 2/24] RUN apt-get update   && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends     ssh     git     m4     libgmp-dev     opam     wget     ca-ce  14.9s
 => [ 3/24] RUN useradd -m bot                                                                                                                     0.2s
 => [ 4/24] WORKDIR /home/bot                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [ 5/24] ADD https://api.github.com/repos/IBM/pycoq/git/refs/heads/main version.json                                                            0.0s
 => [ 6/24] RUN opam init --disable-sandboxing                                                                                                    28.6s
 => => # [ocaml-base-compiler.4.14.0] downloaded from cache at https://opam.ocaml.org/cache
 => => # <><> Processing actions <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
 => => # ∗ installed base-bigarray.base
 => => # ∗ installed base-threads.base
 => => # ∗ installed base-unix.base
 => => # ∗ installed ocaml-options-vanilla.1
```

this failed for me:

```
(meta_learning) brandomiranda~ ❯ docker build -f Dockerfile_arm -t brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test_arm ~/iit-term-synthesis/
[+] Building 0.0s (1/2)
 => ERROR [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile_arm                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 40B                                                                                                                0.0s
------
 > [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile_arm:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender: open .Trash: operation not permitted
```