# Facing the following error while trying to create a Docker Container using a DockerFile -> "error from sender: open .Trash: operation not permitted"

Tags: python, dockerfile

Im completely new to Docker and I'm trying to create and run a very simple example using instructions defined in a DockerFile.

**DockerFile->**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update 

RUN apt-get install -y python3 pip

COPY ./ .

RUN python3 test.py
```

**contents of test.py ->**

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

print('test code')
```

**command being used to create a Docker Container ->**

```
docker build --no-cache . -t intro_to_docker -f abs/path/to/DockerFile
```

folder structure -> (both files are present at abs/path/to)

```
abs/path/to:

    -DockerFile

    -test.py
```

Error message ->

**error from sender: open .Trash: operation not permitted**

(using sudo su did not resolve the issue, which i believe is linked to the copy commands)

I'm using a Mac.

any help in solving this will be much appreciated!

Comment: I use Linux, so not sure with mac, but try just `docker build -t <your_image_name> .`
Do this in the same dir as the Dockerfile (dont forget the ".")

Comment: Also just confirm that you are a root user by running `docker run -it <image_name>` after building without the RUN's in your docker file, apt-get needs sudo or root.

Comment: DockerFile should be Dockerfile as well I believe

Comment: Thank you, changing the working directory to the location that had the Dockerfile (along with renaming the Dockerfile) did the trick!

Comment: put the entire path in the `-f` option e.g: `docker build -f Dockerfile_arm -t brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test_arm ~/iit-term-synthesis/`  see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73642461/1601580

Answer (score 7):

The Dockerfile should be inside a folder. Navigate to that folder and then run docker build command. I was also facing the same issue but got resovled when moved the docker file inside a folder

Comment: put the entire path in the `-f` option e.g: `docker build -f Dockerfile_arm -t brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test_arm ~/iit-term-synthesis/`

Answer (score 4):

It seems the system policies are not allowing the application to execute this command. The application "Terminal" might not have approval to access the entire file system.

Enable full disk access to terminal. Change it using "System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message and my Dockerfile was located in the HOME directory, I moved the Docker file to a different location and executed the docker build from that newly moved location and it successfully executed.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33628197)

Answer (score 1):

Usually the error would look like:

`error: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender: open .Trash: operation not permitted`

And in my case, it's clearly saying that it is unable to find the dockerfile.

*Also, in your command, I see a `.` after `--no-cache`, I think that's not required?*

So better, try navigating to the specified path and then run the build command replacing the `-f` option with a `.`, which specifies the build command to consider the current folder for its build process.

In your case

```sh
cd abs/path/to/
docker build --no-cache -t intro_to_docker .
```

Comment: put the entire path in the `-f` option e.g: `docker build -f Dockerfile_arm -t brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test_arm ~/iit-term-synthesis/`